# How to set Laptop Brightness in Gnome and /proc on Thinkpad W510?

Tags: gnome, thinkpad, acpi

I can set the brightness of my laptop screen already via /proc. I can read and change the value.

Now I've set the value to 33 and then I went into gnome power management and enabled the option that it should reduce the backlight brightness being on battery.

That works, the screen gets darker.

If I now read out the current setting from /proc it still says it's 33. So I assume that there is another node in /proc to be used to control the brightness.

The node I use so far is:

`/proc/acpi/video/VID/LCD0/brightness`

I'm using the nouveau driver. With the nvida driver the brightness can not be controlled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the nvidia driver, the brightness can be controlled the same way, if the according option is activated.

This is done under the Device setting in xorg.conf:

```
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

[Source](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showpost.php?p=2204839&postcount=32)